# Create TPanel which looks like TMainMenu?

Tags: delphi, lazarus

I want to create a component which looks similar to TMainMenu but is based on TPanel.
TMainMenu under Windows 7 has a gradient of colors.

How can I achieve similar effect for TPanel? Not any gradient but a Windows gradient so it looks like a native component.

I also tried TMainMenu.PaintTo but this method is not available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually easy thanks to the UxTheme API (`uses UxTheme`).

Using  [`OpenThemeData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-openthemedata) and [`DrawThemeBackground`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-drawthemebackground),

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin

  var R := Rect(0, 0, ClientWidth, 32);

  var h := OpenThemeData(Handle, 'MENU');
  if h <> 0 then
    try
      DrawThemeBackground(h, Canvas.Handle, MENU_BARBACKGROUND, MB_ACTIVE, R, nil);
    finally
      CloseThemeData(h);
    end;

end;
```

produces

[image: Screenshot of the drawn element in a new VCL form.]

Of course, in a real application, you would refactor this. For instance, you wouldn't hardcode the `32` constant; instead, you'd determine the appropriate menu bar height given current DPI scaling,

Comment: (Also, a disclaimer: I don't know *why* you need this. If you need something that looks like a Win32 menu bar, chances are that you'd be better off with a Win32 menu.)